# Question regarding shunt regualtor using zener diode

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener, shunt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYnVzE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am not able to get proper 3.3volt output at the output capacitor. Since 3.3 volt zener diode have been used, there is a drop in the voltage along zener diode when 3.3v is flowing.

What should I do?

Comment: I suspect it would help if you included a BJT in your circuit to enhance the current compliance. This might require changing the zener, though. Or else using a 2-bjt circuit to lower, then raise back up, the Vbe difference to compensate things a bit. I think you may need to write more about why you want something like this.

Comment: The resistor divider produces 1/11*36 = 3.272 Volts. Your 3.3Volt zener just does not get enough voltage to conduct.

Comment: you can simply remove R2 to address the problem pointed by @Oldfart. You also have to make sure that your load does not drain more than 3.3mA, otherwise you have to lower R1's value

Comment: the input voltage can be minm 36v and max 65v and i want regulated output of 3.3volt which is given to microcontroller. zener didoe have been used as a protection circuit. but i am unable to get constant 3.3volt. there is a drop at the output and microcntrl is not detecting. Plese suggest any changes in circuit or should i add series  resistor with zenerdiode.

Comment: Are you powering the MCU with this circuit? If so, what is the maximum expected current draw? How accurate does the 3.3V have to be?

Comment: we have taken as analog signal and given to mcu.
maximum current draw is 50mA W.R.T MCU. mcu pin voltage range is 0 to 3.5v.
for bringup purpose i want constant 3.3volt to come.but there is a drop until unless we dont remove the diode.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please note that voltage isn't flowing. Current is flowing.

Comment: If you are using this circuit as reference voltage for MCU, then it's a really bad idea.

Comment: See leakage current of the zener

Comment: any suggestion, why there is a drop in the output voltage?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove R2 in your circuit, you should be able to measure the requested 3.3V reference voltage at the output of the capacitor.